# Scientifically possible superpower that has the most impact on daily life

Tags: technology

Nowadays people can get magnet implants from  specialized piercers to feel magnetic fields around them and gain a new sense.

What other super powers can be achieved with today's or near future (about 10-20 years) technology. I'm looking for something that can actually alter daily life almost completely or make everything different or easier, since having magnet implants is cool but not the most useful thing ever.

Comment: We don't make lists, and you are giving no criteria to pick the value of a superpower. Please narrow it down and make it sharper.

Comment: Sigh.  Eventually I'll learn what questions not to answer.  I was 3/4 done typing an answer when this closed...

Comment: Compound eyes !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Echolocation, which doesn't actually require any implants, it's a trained skill. The visually impaired learn this skill and are able to tell where objects are by emitting a clicking sound with their tongue or hitting the pavement with a rod and having the sound bounce back from objects. People with good vision can also train this skill to be able to navigate in the dark or potentially tell where things are behind them. (Like Daredevil but much lower resolution)

And if you want to enhance it with implants, too can get ultra high frequency sound sensor implants that would be able to detect sound of a much smaller wavelength, giving you much better resolution with your echolocation.